# How to generate map with included map basing on list of integers?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of ids like

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList(){1,2,3};
```

I need to transform this to the map of next structure:

`Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>` where keys will be ids from the list and map will be just empty map. Of course I can create new map, after that I can iterate over the list and to put id and new HashMap<String,String> to that new map. But is it possible to do that in one stream? Using `generate()` and `collect()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Collectors.toMap(...)

```
ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap( 
    Function.identity(), 
    id -> new HashMap<String, String>() 
));
```

`Collectors.toMap` requires two parameters: firstly, a key mapper, in our case, we'll use the current id from the stream, so `id -> id` or simply `Function.identity()`.

Then, for the value mapper, for each id, we are creating a new HashMap(), Additionally, you can declare it as `__ -> new HashMap<String, String>()` (using "__" as the name of the element from the steram would suggest you are not interested in its value, and all the value mappers are returning the same).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) the stream to map using [Collectors.toMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). Example:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
    Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> result = ids.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(num -> num, num -> new HashMap<>()));
  }
}
```